# How can I configure multiple AWS accounts in metricbreat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-stack, elk, metricbeat

I am using `metricbeat` to collect metrics from AWS. I am looking for a better way to collect from multiple AWS accounts. Below is my configuration and I am using `credential_profile_name` to specify AWS profile name. But how I can add more names in this field? I have tried to use comma `,` or space as separator but none of them work.

```
- module: aws
  period: 5m
  metricsets:
    - cloudwatch
  credential_profile_name: t00
  regions:
    - ap-southeast-2
  metrics:
    - namespace: AWS/EC2
      #name: ["CPUUtilization", "DiskWriteOps"]
      resource_type: ec2:instance
    - namespace: "*"
```

I understand that I can duplicate the configuration change use different profile name for each. But I need to manage many AWS accounts and it is hard to duplicate many configurations. Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: What happens if you add another `-module: aws` section? I.e. duplicate what you have already and use a different `credential_profile_name:` value

Comment: it would work but I am looking for a simpler way. I have to duplicate a lot configuration since I have many AWS accounts.

Comment: If it works, then it's probably the only way (if I recall correctly when I read through the docs and some GitHbu issues on their repository). You'd need to use a script or a configuration management tool to generate that config if you wanted to simplify it.